# Applying log on both sides to decide whether $f(n)=O(g(n))$ or $g(n) = O(f(n))$?

Tags: calculus, algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics, computer-science

If i have to decide which function is bigger, can i apply logarithm on both sides and infer?

For example, $n $ vs $\sqrt n$

[On face of it i know that n>$\sqrt n$]

If i apply log function

$\ln n $ vs $\frac{1}{2} \ln n$

Both are asymtotically equal(differing by constant?) But it is not true right?

[To decide whether (In algorithm Big oh notation, )$f(x) = O(g(x))$]

**My doubt is
If i had to decide whether $f(n)=O(g(n))$ or $g(n) = O(f(n))$, i apply log on both sides. Some times it does not give right answer(for instance above one). Can you pls tell when will applying log on both sides go wrong?**

I am a beginner. kindly clarify.

Comment: Not really true, let see example  1/2 > 1/3   but log (1/2) > log (1/3) is wrong

Comment: $\ln$ is increasing function, as base is more, then one, so, for all $0\lt x \lt y$ we have $\ln x \lt \ln y$. Your last questions is little unclear for me, but, anyway $O(\ln n) = O\left( \frac{1}{2}\ln n \right)$.  Can you clarify the question ?

Comment: @nimmy $\log(1/2) > \log(1/3)$ is correct...

Comment: Let me add, that monotone of $\log_a x$ depend on its base $a$. If $a \gt 1$ it's increasing, if $0 \lt a \lt 1$, then decreasing, so inequality depends on $a$. Without knowing base it's impossible to make conclusion. For $\ln$, as I wrote above, it's increasing.

Comment: $\ln n>\frac12\ln n$ only if $n>1$.

Comment: My doubt is
If i had to decide whether $f(n)=O(g(n))$ or $g(n) = O(f(n))$, i apply log on both sides. Some times it does not give right answer(for instance above one). Can you pls tell when will applying log on both sides go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $f(x) = O(g(n))$ is that exists $C$ such that $|f(n)| \le C |g(n)|$ for $n$ big enough.

Applying $\log$ preserves inequalities, BUT transforms products into sums. Since the definition of $f(n) = O(g(n))$ involves a product, $f(n) = O(g(n))$ is NOT equivalent to $\log f(n) = O(\log g(n))$.

For example, take $f(n)=n^2$ and $g(n) = n$, then $\log f(n) = O(\log g(n))$ but $f(n) \ne O(g(n))$.

On the other hand, take $f(n) = 1/n$ and $g(n)=1$. Then $f(n)=O(g(n))$ but $\log f(n) \ne O(\log g(n))$.

So neither of the implications

$f(n) = O(g(n)) \implies \log f(n) = O(\log g(n))$

$\log f(n) = O(\log g(n)) \implies f(n) = O(g(n))$

is true.

Comment: Nice! Is there any function where such equivalence exists? I am going thru this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948606/taking-the-log-of-both-sides-to-determine-big-theta-omega-o?rq=1 (i did not understand the 2nd part of answer. Which functions of form $phi$ will satisfy equivalence)

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote above $\sqrt{n} \lt n$ implies $\ln\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{2}\ln n \lt \ln n$.

This fact does not interfere with the fact that  $O(\ln n) = O\left( \frac{1}{2}\ln n \right)$. It's possible, that $f(n) \lt g(n)$, but $O(f)=O(g)$, as it gives brought example. We have  $O(\sqrt{n} )\subset O(n)$ strictly.

On another hand, words "asymptotically equal", "same order of magnitude" usually, is used for big-$\Theta$ notation, not for big-$O$. Used this notation we can say, again, that despite that $\sqrt{n}$ and $n$ **are not** asymptotically equal, i.e. $\Theta(\sqrt{n})\ne \Theta(n)$,  the for pair $\ln\sqrt{n}$ and $\ln n$ holds $\Theta(\ln\sqrt{n})=\Theta(\ln n)$.

So, we can formulate little rule: increasing function doesn't keep "asymptotically not equality".

**Addition**.

Let me first present the answer in the form of an affirmative and then a negative sentence. Suppose we generalize the notion of positive functions asymptotically equivalent to the notion of having the same order, i.e., when there is a limit $\lim\frac{f}{g}=L\gt 0$. If all conditions of Lopital's rule are satisfied for given functions, then, assuming that all expressions written out make sense, we have $\lim\frac{\ln f}{\ln g} = \lim\frac{ \frac{ 1}{ f}f'}{\frac{ 1}{ g}g'} = 1$. So, we can say, that in described conditions, if $f,g$ have same order, then $\ln f,\ln g$ also will have same order. As negative sentence we can formulate it in following way: if $\ln f,\ln g$ have not same order, then $f, g$ also will not have same order.

Comment: $\ln\sqrt n$ and $\ln n$ are _not_ asymptotically equal; their ratio doesn't tend to $1$. See [here](https://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/AsymptoticallyEqual.html) or [here](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/HANDOUTS/asympineq.pdf).

Comment: @TonyK. Usually, of course, definition of $\sim$ use limit equality to $1$, but, look, please, that above I used it as synonym of $\Theta$ classes equality. Anyway, I edited it, thanks.

Comment: @zkutch  Sir, My doubt is
If i had to decide whether $f(n)=O(g(n))$ or $g(n) = O(f(n))$, i apply log on both sides. Some times it does not give right answer(for instance above one). Can you pls tell when will applying log on both sides go wrong?

Comment: Let me think a little, please.

Comment: @Nascimento de Cos. Wrote little addition, as promised, in hope it helps.